# Bernoulli polynomials identity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Apostol

5.9.35

Given $P_0(x) = 1,\; P_n'(x) = nP_{n-1}(x),\; \int_0^1{P_n(x) \ dx} = 0 \enspace \forall \:n\geq 1$

(f)Prove that

$$ P_n(1-x) = {(-1)}^n P_n(x)$$

if $n\geq 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $P_{n-1}(1-x) = (-1)^{n-1}P_{n-1}(x)$. Then \begin{eqnarray}\frac{d}{dx}[P_n(1-x) - (-1)^{n}P_n(x)] &&= -nP_{n-1}(1-x) -n(-1)^{n}P_{n-1}(x) \\ &&= -n(P_{n-1}(1-x) - (-1)^{n-1}P_{n-1}(x)) = 0\\ \end{eqnarray}

so $P_n(1-x) - (-1)^{n}P_n(x)$ will be a constant $C$. By taking $x = 0$ and then $x = 1$ we can deduce, if $n$ is even, that $C = -C$, so $C = 0$. If $n$ is odd then we can take $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and similarly obtain $C = 0$.

As an aside, if you're trying to learn rigorous calculus, I recommend you look at *Advanced Calculus* by R. Creighton Buck.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it later. I have got used to Apostol's methods and it would not be good if I break it during the course.